# How to use jetpack.storage.setting in Jetpack SDK 0.9

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

When we use Jetpack 0.6, we could manifest something like this,

```
var manifest = {
  settings: [
    {
      name: "foo",
      type: "group",
      label: "Twitter Account",
      settings: [
        { name: "twitterId", type: "text", label: "Username" },
        { name: "twitterPass", type: "password", label: "Password" }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

jetpack.future.import("storage.settings");
```

Does anyone know how to do same thing in Jetpack SDK 0.9.
Which module should I use?

Answer (score 1):

the import has changed to something like: var simpleStorage = require("simple-storage");

see: https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/sdk/0.9/docs/#module/addon-kit/simple-storage